# Go on, mock my IDE

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rubberduck, mocks

Because of the coupling with the VBIDE API (the extensibility library for the VBA IDE), unit testing the [rubberduck](/questions/tagged/rubberduck) refactorings, inspections and quick-fixes has been pretty much impossible, at least until a `MockFactory` was implemented, to do things like this:

```
internal static Mock<CodeModule> CreateCodeModuleMock(string code)
{
    var lines = code.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

    var codeModule = new Mock<CodeModule>();
    codeModule.SetupGet(c => c.CountOfLines).Returns(lines.Count);

    codeModule.Setup(m => m.get_Lines(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns<int, int>((start, count) => String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.Skip(start - 1).Take(count)));

    codeModule.Setup(m => m.ReplaceLine(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<int, string>((index, str) => lines[index - 1] = str);

    codeModule.Setup(m => m.DeleteLines(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Callback<int, int>((index, count) => lines.RemoveRange(index - 1, count));

    codeModule.Setup(m => m.InsertLines(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<int, string>((index, newLine) => lines.Insert(index - 1, newLine));

    return codeModule;
}
```

The `MockFactory` is used extensively in an abstract class from which to derive all unit tests that need to work with the VBIDE API:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using Rubberduck.VBEditor;
using MockFactory = RubberduckTests.Mocks.MockFactory;

namespace RubberduckTests
{
    public abstract class VbeTestBase
    {
        private Mock<VBE> _ide;
        private ICollection<VBProject> _projects;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            _ide = MockFactory.CreateVbeMock();
            _ide.SetupProperty(m => m.ActiveCodePane);
            _ide.SetupProperty(m => m.ActiveVBProject);
            _ide.SetupGet(m => m.SelectedVBComponent).Returns(() => _ide.Object.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.Parent);
            _ide.SetupGet(m => m.ActiveWindow).Returns(() => _ide.Object.ActiveCodePane.Window);

            _projects = new List<VBProject>();
            var projects = MockFactory.CreateProjectsMock(_projects);
            projects.Setup(m => m.Item(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(i => _projects.ElementAt(i));

            _ide.SetupGet(m => m.VBProjects).Returns(() => projects.Object);
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            _ide = null;
        }

        protected QualifiedSelection GetQualifiedSelection(Selection selection)
        {
            if (_ide.Object.ActiveCodePane == null)
            {
                _ide.Object.ActiveVBProject = _ide.Object.VBProjects.Item(0);
                _ide.Object.ActiveCodePane = _ide.Object.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Item(0).CodeModule.CodePane;
            }
            return GetQualifiedSelection(selection, _ide.Object.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.Parent);
        }

        protected QualifiedSelection GetQualifiedSelection(Selection selection, VBComponent component)
        {
            return new QualifiedSelection(new QualifiedModuleName(component), selection);
        }

        protected Mock<VBProject> SetupMockProject(string inputCode, string projectName = null, string moduleName = null, vbext_ComponentType? componentType = null)
        {
            if (componentType == null)
            {
                componentType = vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule;
            }

            if (moduleName == null)
            {
                moduleName = componentType == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule 
                    ? "Module1" 
                    : componentType == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ClassModule
                        ? "Class1"
                        : componentType == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_MSForm
                            ? "Form1"
                            : "Document1";
            }

            if (projectName == null)
            {
                projectName = "VBAProject";
            }

            var component = CreateMockComponent(inputCode, moduleName, componentType.Value);
            var components = new List<Mock<VBComponent>> {component};

            var project = CreateMockProject(projectName, vbext_ProjectProtection.vbext_pp_none, components);
            return project;
        }

        protected Mock<VBProject> CreateMockProject(string name, vbext_ProjectProtection protection, ICollection<Mock<VBComponent>> components)
        {
            var project = MockFactory.CreateProjectMock(name, protection);
            var projectComponents = SetupMockComponents(components, project.Object);

            project.SetupGet(m => m.VBE).Returns(_ide.Object);
            project.SetupGet(m => m.VBComponents).Returns(projectComponents.Object);

            _projects.Add(project.Object);
            return project;
        }

        protected Mock<VBComponent> CreateMockComponent(string content, string name, vbext_ComponentType type)
        {
            var module = SetupMockCodeModule(content, name);
            var component = MockFactory.CreateComponentMock(name, module.Object, type, _ide);

            module.SetupGet(m => m.Parent).Returns(component.Object);
            return component;
        }


        private Mock<VBComponents> SetupMockComponents(ICollection<Mock<VBComponent>> items, VBProject project)
        {
            var components = MockFactory.CreateComponentsMock(items, project);
            components.SetupGet(m => m.Parent).Returns(project);
            components.SetupGet(m => m.VBE).Returns(_ide.Object);
            components.Setup(m => m.Item(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int index) => items.ElementAt(index).Object);
            components.Setup(m => m.Item(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string name) => items.Single(e => e.Name == name).Object);

            return components;
        }

        private Mock<CodeModule> SetupMockCodeModule(string content, string name)
        {
            var codePane = MockFactory.CreateCodePaneMock(_ide, name);
            var module = MockFactory.CreateCodeModuleMock(content, codePane, _ide);

            codePane.SetupGet(m => m.CodeModule).Returns(module.Object);
            return module;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty confident that this setup will allow us to write a bunch of unit tests for the reference resolver, refactorings and code inspections.

The `SetupMockProject` overload with the optional parameters was already called by 39 tests when I started refactoring it to support mocking an IDE with as many code modules and projects as needed (I still need to make it support project references and form designer though); in order to keep the existing tests green and the test project compilable, I decided to add optional parameters... and I'm not sure I like the result.

Other than that, I find the code pretty clean and the resulting API pretty neat. Anything I missed? The `MockFactory` class (as is the rest of the project) is [on GitHub](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/22cc37b8cdfe19ca742f23b2718ca4a7a4b0d9e9/RubberduckTests/Mocks/MockFactory.cs), for reference (points to this version of the code).

Comment: You'll also want to make `Initialize` overridable so child classes can safely add to the test initialization. As it is, I don't think there's a guarantee of execution order of you add another `TestInitialize` in a child class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Almost all of this code can (should?) be moved directly into the `MockFactory`.

> ```
>         [TestInitialize]
>         public void Initialize()
>         {
>             _ide = MockFactory.CreateVbeMock();
>             _ide.SetupProperty(m => m.ActiveCodePane);
>             _ide.SetupProperty(m => m.ActiveVBProject);
>             _ide.SetupGet(m => m.SelectedVBComponent).Returns(() => _ide.Object.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.Parent);
>             _ide.SetupGet(m => m.ActiveWindow).Returns(() => _ide.Object.ActiveCodePane.Window);
>
>             _projects = new List<VBProject>();
>             var projects = MockFactory.CreateProjectsMock(_projects);
>             projects.Setup(m => m.Item(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(i => _projects.ElementAt(i));
>
>             _ide.SetupGet(m => m.VBProjects).Returns(() => projects.Object);
>         }
> ```

I imagine that the initialize method could be much simpler and look like this.

```
_ide = MockFactory.CreateVbeMock();

_projects = new List<VBProject>();
var projects = MockFactory.CreateProjectsMock(_projects);

_ide.SetupGet(m => m.VBProjects).Returns(() => projects.Object);
```

I find this signature to be a bit strange too.

> ```
> protected Mock<VBProject> SetupMockProject(string inputCode, string projectName = null, string moduleName = null, vbext_ComponentType? componentType = null)
> ```

This is probably fine so long as you're only interested in mocking up a project with a single code module, but you'll quickly find yourself in need of a proper collection of modules. This method should have an overload that takes in an `IEnumerable<VBComponent>`, or perhaps an `AddComponent` method would be better.

Comment: That. Exactly that. Several times I found myself wondering if such or such mock setup was in the `MockFactory` or in the class I was refactoring. Definitely a responsibility overlap here. Bang on!

Answer (score 20):

> ```
> if (moduleName == null)
> {
>     moduleName = componentType == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule 
>         ? "Module1" 
>         : componentType == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ClassModule
>             ? "Class1"
>             : componentType == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_MSForm
>                 ? "Form1"
>                 : "Document1";
> }
> ```

Sorry, that I have to say this, but this is **UGLY**. Why don't you use a dictionary which is easily expandable if needed and would make the getting of the `moduleName` more **shining**?

If you don't want a dictionary, you really should extract it to a separate method where you simply should use a `switch` instead of this ugly and unreadable ternary construct.

---

Checking items for `null` by using an `if` statement and if it is `null` assign a default value, so it can be handled nicer using the [null coalescing operator `??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

So for example this:

> ```
> if (componentType == null)
> {
>     componentType = vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule;
> }
> ```

would become this:

```
componentType = componentType ?? vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule;
```

---

After a second glance at the `abstract class VbeTestBase` I wonder why you decided to make this class `abstract`. You don't have neither `abstract` methods nor properties, hence there isn't any reason why this class should be `abstract`.

Comment: You know, the worst part is that *I know* these things. What I don't know is *why do I still write code like that*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Laziness, bad habits?

Comment: @BadHorsie What's lazy about writing it *the longer way*? :D

Comment: Is there a `??=` operator in VBA? :-D

Comment: @JanDvorak not that I am aware of and I think it would be good if there wasn't one.

Comment: @Luaan Not laziness about writing it the long way, laziness about knowing it's wrong but can't be bothered to do it the proper way!

Comment: To deliberately misquote a famous saying, "I would have made it shorter, but I just couldn't be bothered"