# Performing and timing loops with SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, benchmarking

I am a casual C# programmer, not formally trained in OOP at all; mostly I focus on Transact-SQL in SQL Server, and so when I write C# apps I get grief about the constructs and methods I use. Here is a simple app I wrote for [this blog post](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/08/sql-server-2016/perf-impact-always-encrypted) - it was not meant to be a production app, and performance is certainly not a priority, but I would like to become better at writing optimal code naturally.

The purpose of the code is quite simple - for 100,000 cycles I need to generate a random name and number from a SQL Server stored procedure, then write those values to a table . After that, read 100 random rows from the table, 1,000 times, and not really care what is done as you iterate through the 100 rows.

The point of the exercise was to profile the effects of encryption on the application. So what the reader loop does is not really material and does not need to be optimized, it is just there to take up time and be the same in both cases. Also it should be noted that the multiple connections are intentional - it is supposed to simulate - without getting into multi-threading or multiple instances of the app - all of the overhead you would see in a highly concurrent app (even though, deep down, this still executes serially).

Items that were pointed out to me (and that I'd like to better understand):

- `for` is better than `while`
- Variable declaration at the top is bad
- Code is bloated
- Legibility is bad

I am also sure there is a better way to *time* the performance of the code, other than dumping the current clock time to the console.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AEDemo
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
        string name;
        string EmptyString = "";
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[args[0]].ToString();
        int salary;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 100000)
        {
          con1.ConnectionString = conString;
          using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.GenerateNameAndSalary", con1))
          {
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter n = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32) 
                             { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
            SqlParameter s = new SqlParameter("@Salary", SqlDbType.Int) 
                             { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
            cmd1.Parameters.Add(n);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add(s);
            con1.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            name = n.Value.ToString();
            salary = Convert.ToInt32(s.Value);
            con1.Close();
          }

          using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection())
          {
            con2.ConnectionString = conString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddPerson", con2))
            {
              cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              SqlParameter n = new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32);
              SqlParameter s = new SqlParameter("@Salary", SqlDbType.Int);
              n.Value = name;
              s.Value = salary;
              cmd2.Parameters.Add(n);
              cmd2.Parameters.Add(s);
              con2.Open();
              cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
              con2.Close();
            }
          }
          i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
        i = 1;
        while (i <= 1000)
        {
          using (SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection())
          {
            con3.ConnectionString = conString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("dbo.RetrievePeople", con3))
            {
              cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              con3.Open();
              SqlDataReader rdr = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
              while (rdr.Read())
              {
                EmptyString += rdr[0].ToString();
              }
              con3.Close();
            }
          }
          i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long *does* this take to execute, on average?

Comment: @EBrown Over 5 runs these were the averages: http://cdn.sqlperformance.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/AE-Perf.png

Comment: I guess [this title](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96319/11852) is ok, then?

Comment: lol @AaronBertrand you should discuss that with him in chat.  but that title explains very briefly what the code is about.

Comment: @Malachi So did my original title, I thought.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the case of **both** if your `while` loops, you could *easily* make them `for` loops instead, which tends to be the best practice.

```
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 100000)
    {
        // main while code
        i++
    }
```

**Should** be rewritten as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
{
    // main while code
}
```

Likewise:

```
    i = 1;
    while (i <= 1000)
    {
        // main while code
        i++;
    }
```

Would become:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    // main while code
}
```

This allows you to recycle the variable `i` later, and also prevents from accidentally forgetting to reset `i` back to `1` between loops. Generally, the variable `i` stands for `iterator`, and is typically reserved *exclusively* for loops.

This has no real performance impact, but it has a **severe** readability and maintainability impact. Using the `for` loop, it is **immediately clear** what is happening to the iterator. Using the `while` loop, you have to search through the body of the `while` to find where you manipulate the iterator.

---

As far as:

> variable declaration at the top is bad

Generally it *is* frowned upon. You should declare variables *as close* to their usage as possible, and within the tightest block that they are to be used in.

For example, the:

> ```
>    int salary;
>    string name;
> ```

**Should** be declared within your first loop (which should now be a `for` loop):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
{
    int salary;
    string name;
}
```

This is so that variables cannot unexpectedly be used in places where they should not, and so that they can be recycled when they fall out-of-scope immediately. It also means that you cannot accidentally use the value of them outside of the block they apply to.

---

Try to choose more effective variable names. Never abbreviate except for certain well-accepted abbreviates (`i` for `iterator`, `e` for `eventArgs`, etc.):

```
  using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection())
  {
```

Would be *more accepted* as:

```
  using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection())
  {
```

This is mostly a best-practice.

---

You are likely going to see a **huge** performance drag using the `EmptyString` variable as you are: `string` types are immutable, which means each time you do `EmptyString += rdr[0].ToString();` it creates a new instance of a string with the combination, then assigns it to `EmptyString`, then schedules the original string for garbage collection.

Instead, use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder emptyStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    // ...
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        emptyStringBuilder.Append(rdr[0].ToString());
    }
    // ...
}
```

This saves a **lot** of performance. [See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

---

Another variable naming nit-pick: you should always `camelCase` local and `private` variable names: i.e. `emptyString` instead of `EmptyString`.

This is another best-practice.

---

After all our rewrites:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AEDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[args[0]].ToString();

                for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
                {
                    connection1.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                    string name;
                    int salary;

                    using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.GenerateNameAndSalary", connection1))
                    {
                        command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlParameter nameParameter = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                        SqlParameter salaryParameter = new SqlParameter("@Salary", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

                        command1.Parameters.Add(nameParameter);
                        command1.Parameters.Add(salaryParameter);

                        connection1.Open();
                        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        name = nameParameter.Value.ToString();
                        salary = Convert.ToInt32(salaryParameter.Value);
                        connection1.Close();
                    }

                    using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection())
                    {
                        connection2.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                        using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddPerson", connection2))
                        {
                            command2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            SqlParameter nameParameter = new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32);
                            SqlParameter salaryParameter = new SqlParameter("@Salary", SqlDbType.Int);
                            nameParameter.Value = name;
                            salaryParameter.Value = salary;

                            command2.Parameters.Add(nameParameter);
                            command2.Parameters.Add(salaryParameter);

                            connection2.Open();
                            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            connection2.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));

                // We'll declare the StringBuilder outside the `for` to get maximum performance impact, and demonstrate it's effectiveness
                StringBuilder emptyStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection())
                    {
                        connection3.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                        using (SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("dbo.RetrievePeople", connection3))
                        {
                            command3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            command3.Open();

                            SqlDataReader reader = command3.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                emptyStringBuilder.Append(reader[0].ToString());
                            }
                            connection3.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ### Disclaimer
>
> I wrote this outside the IDE, there may be minor changes required to make it work.

---

> Also I am sure there is a better way to *time* the performance of the code, other than dumping the current clock time to the console.

Yes, you should look into [the Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) for timing. It's **much** more accurate than using `DateTime` strings printed to the `Console`. It also allows you to easily reset it and such, so you could build a very effective diagnostics procedure that would measure the specific performance impacts that you are trying to.

---

I also recommend you take Malachi's advice on the connection string.

---

And finally, after discussion in the comments, I would recommend you build a class to represent the return of `dbo.RetrievePeople`. Then, you should create an instance of that class instead of the `emptyStringBuilder.Append`, and add each instance to a `List<T>`. This will allow you to performance test with more relation to what would **likely** be the actual use-case.

---

Glad to see you over here, you're a legend on the DBA site! :)

Comment: Thanks, the performance of the iterator is not what I am looking to optimize, at all. In fact I wrote that intentionally to be slow.

Comment: The iterator's are not slow, the adding a string to a string part is. Depending on what you are trying to measure (performance wise) it would be best to use a `StringBuilder` there so you don't get noise from the creation/recycling of excess resources.

Comment: Okay, but I'm trying to make the app *do something*, even if it's wasteful, like real applications do.

Comment: you should move the connection string assignment outside of the for loop

Comment: @AaronBertrand The question is, are you trying to test how it would perform on the application, or on the SQL server? If you want to stress-test the SQL server, then you would be better off using the `StringBuilder` as that bit will be **significantly** faster, and come back to the SQL server for more work **almost immediately**. (I assume that is your goal?)

Comment: I'm trying to test end-to-end - what is the impact to end users. I don't care so much what percentage of the delta is due to the app, and what percentage is due to network, and what percentage is due to SQL Server. In the case of "I'm writing an app for production" or "I'm demonstrating how to write optimized C#" then yes, absolutely, I know to use StringBuilder. But I was intentionally doing something here so that the time the reader loop took would be tangible.

Comment: @AaronBertrand What I would recommend then, is building a POCO to represent what data is coming from the `dbo.RetrievePeople` SP, and then load each record into an instance of that POCO, and add each instance of that POCO to a `List<POCO>`. This will allow you to get a much better feel for how an actual application would respond in such a scenario. :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand the string concatenation has quadratic performance cost. This is not representative of real applications. I understand your need to cause *some* processing, but it should be linear in the number of rows. Not quadratic.

Comment: All of the connection `.Close()`s can be eliminated since the `using` block takes care of closing the connections.

Answer (score 11):

Why isn't `using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection())` inside your `while` loop, right before `using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.GenerateNameAndSalary", con1))`?

Right now `con1` is instantiated on line 14 and not disposed until line 82, yet it isn't used after line 39. You actually open `con2` inside the `con1` `using` block, as well as `con3` which is inside `while (i <= 1000)`.

---

This:

```
SqlParameter n = new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32);
SqlParameter s = new SqlParameter("@Salary", SqlDbType.Int);
n.Value = name;
s.Value = salary;
cmd2.Parameters.Add(n);
cmd2.Parameters.Add(s);
```

... can be rewritten as:

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32).Value = name;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Salary", SqlDbType.Int).Value = salary;
```

---

Why do this:

```
using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection())
{
    con2.ConnectionString = conString;
```

... when `SqlConnection` has [a constructor that accepts the connection string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0(v=vs.110).aspx)?

---

No need to do `con1.Close();`, `con2.Close();` etc. since [the connection is inside a `using` block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195854/648075).

---

You need to [wrap `SqlDataReader` inside a using block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985968/648075) as well.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed the `SqlDataReader` not having a `using` block. Good answer!

Answer (score 8):

You should move your connection string outside of the using statement

```
  using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
    string name;
    string EmptyString = "";
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[args[0]].ToString();
    int salary;
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 100000)
    {
      con1.ConnectionString = conString;
```

Like this

```
  string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[args[0]].ToString();

  using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(conString))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
    string name;
    string EmptyString = "";
    int salary;
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 100000)
    {
```

by doing this you eliminate the need to set the connection string in the `SqlConnection` object later in the code.

You can also leave out the calls to close the connections, this happens automatically when scope leaves the using statements.

---

I would think that the connection to the Database shouldn't have anything to do with the rest of the code.  You could actually use the same connection for each and every operation in this application, and it should give you a better idea of how each operation is being handled.

another thing that I would suggest is not calling `Console.WriteLine` until the end of the method.  By that I mean that you should hold the times in variables, declared before all the fun starts, assign the variables where you currently have `Console.WriteLine` and then when everything is said and done you could then write them out to the Console.

This would take the heavy process of `Console.WriteLine` out of the equation for figuring the timing of these processes

---

There is also a way that you can use a using statement surrounding the `SqlDataReader` as well.

You have to create the reader and then put it into a using statement like this

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
using (rdr)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        EmptyString += rdr[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

it's a little different than a command or a connection but a data reader still implements the IDisposable interface and should be disposed up properly should anything happen while it is being used.

---

As far as the loops go, a for loop is going to look cleaner and be a little easier to maintain should you have to change something in the code later.

- declare incrementation variable in for loop declaration
- handle incrementation in the for loop declaration
- handle how many loops in the for loop declaration

with a while loop you can only do one of these inside the declaration, the rest have to be done elsewhere in the code and could lead to unexpected incrementation or something else changing the incrementation variable.

with a for loop the incrementation variable is scoped to the loop and destroyed when the scope leaves the for loop.  In your while loop the incrementation variable is still usable after the while loop is exited, and you don't need to access that value so why do that?

Comment: Can you explain *why* that is better? Remember, I *want* to connect to the database 100,000 times, not once, so that handshake overhead is part of the profile.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Moving the `conString` to the constructor of the `SqlConnection` **will not** connect to the database. It merely saves you wasting resources on resetting that variable to the exact same thing 100,000 times.

Comment: For the connection strings actually there are different connections used, I just simplified slightly. And for the console.writeline stuff, you can assume that a real application that is interacting with data will actually *do stuff*. Since the cost of writing a datetime to the console should be the same in all cases, does it really matter if that additional bit of time is always included in all tests or never included in any tests? I'm trying to measure *relative* performance, not absolute.

Comment: you should post the code that is closest to the actual code as possible, otherwise you will get reviews on stuff that doesn't fit your actual code.

Comment: Settle down, I just consolidated two separate conString variables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, lol sometimes we get questions where the OP has changed vital pieces of the code, and when we review they say, that doesn't matter to me because I am doing x in my actual code.  happens a lot.  if that's the only thing I can understand that.  just keep in mind that is why I said that, and that I mentioned the connection string thing because I thought they were all the same.

Answer (score 8):

## `for` loops

Rather than using a `while` loop, and having an iterator variable `i`, You can use a [`for`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop. A simple `for` loop is structured something like this:

```
for(/* Declare `i` */; /* Check the value of `i` against a condition */; /* Change the value of `i` */)
{
    ...
}
```

For example, this `while` loop, near the beginning of your code:

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= 100000)
{
    ...
}
```

Would become the following `for` loop

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100000; ++i)
{

}
```

By using a `for` loop, you can eliminate the need to declare `i`, and increment it on a separate line.

---

## Separation of repeated code

I've noticed that you're repeated this line of code three times:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
```

While in a small program like this, it isn't such a huge deal, I'd recommend encapsulating this in a helper method, like this:

```
private void CurrentUtcDate()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"));
}
```

You can then add this method to your `Program` class, and call `this.CurrentUtcDate()`, or `CurrentUtcDate()` to achieve the same effect.

---

## Nitpicks

I don't see many things about this code that I need to nitpick, but here's a few things that could be changed:

- Add some blank lines in your `Main` method. This will help improve readability.
- Drop some inline comments `//` in there as well, explaining what certain blocks of code do, and how they do that.
- Remove the useless `using` statements at the top of your code, like `System.Collections.Generic`, and `System.Text`.

Comment: IIRC if I removed `System.Configuration` I was not able to pull `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` from `App.Config`. Also is the `while` -> `for` a worthwhile change (given that most of my SQL Server-based readers have much more familiarity with `while` than `for`), or more of a micro-optimization?

Comment: `CurrentUtcDate()` isn't very descriptive, and has unexpected side effects. I would go with something like `PrintCurrentUtcDate()` or `PrintDate(DateTime date)` and call `PrintDate(DateTime.UtcNow)`.